# How to calculate no of days in current date in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm working on an iPhone application.

How can I get number of days from current year first date to current date in iPhone.

I tried with this code:
  NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

```
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:self toDate:aDate options:0];

return [components day];
```

But when i give from date is: jan /01/2013  todate is: dec/12/31 i got 363 day. But we have 365 days.

Please help me to out of this issue. Thanks.

Comment: What??????????? I understood it up to "first date to current date in iPhone" when you just confused the hell out of me.

Comment: Please tell us what you have already tried and what is your problem with that code!

Comment: @popeye have u got my question?

Comment: My initial impression is you want to know how many days there have been from x day (1st Jan 2013) to y day (Todays date). Is that correct? If so please share what you have tried and make you question make more sense.

Comment: @HAS Friend i need to get no of days from current year first date to cyrrent date. I need to get current date total day from current year.

Comment: friend i tried this below code : yearstart date is current year strat date: difference = [[picker date]  numberOfDaysUntil:yearstartdate]; When i give in picker date: dec/31/2013 my number of days remaining is 363, but total days is 365 right?

Comment: please chane self to [NSDate date], i thik you got it

Answer (score 2):

`NSCalendar` is your friend:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger days = [cal ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                 inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit forDate:now];
```

Result for today (Dec 11, 2013): `345`.

Comment: @user1547937: If my answer helped it would really be nice if you "accept" it by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can get number of days between two dates.

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                fromDate:date

                                                  toDate:toDate
                                                 options:0];
    NSInteger days = [components day];
    ;
    return days;
```